# What are the alternatives to RCTEventEmitter and RCTModernEventEmitter?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I am trying to integrate a `Native UI` component in `react-native` using the `new architecture` with `fabric` enabled

Here is my spec file

```
import type {HostComponent, ViewProps} from 'react-native';
import type {
  DirectEventHandler,
  BubblingEventHandler,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/Types/CodegenTypes';
import codegenNativeComponent from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent';

type Event = Readonly<{
  text?: string;
}>;

interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
  text: string;
  onClickHandler?: DirectEventHandler<Event>; ////Event name should start with on
}

export default codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
  'MyButtonView',
) as HostComponent<NativeProps>;
```

Then on native side I created following files

```
public class MyButtonViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<MyButtonView> {

    public static final String NAME = "MyButtonView";
    ReactApplicationContext mCallerContext;

    public MyButtonViewManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        mCallerContext = reactContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected MyButtonView createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new MyButtonView(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "text")
    public void setQrCodeText(MyButtonView view, String text) {
        view.setText(text);
    }
    

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants() {
        return MapBuilder.of("topOnClickHandler",
                MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onClickHandler")
        );
    }

}


public class MyButtonView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {

    public MyButtonView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        configureViews();
    }

    private void configureViews(){
        setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        setOnClickListener(view -> {
            ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();
            EventDispatcher eventDispatcher = UIManagerHelper.getEventDispatcherForReactTag(
                    reactContext ,getId()
            );
            eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new MyButtonClickEvent(getId()));
        });
    }
}

public class MyButtonClickEvent extends Event<MyButtonClickEvent> {

    public MyButtonClickEvent(int viewId) {
        super(viewId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getEventName() {
        return "topOnClickHandler";
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatch(RCTEventEmitter rctEventEmitter) {
        super.dispatch(rctEventEmitter);
        rctEventEmitter.receiveEvent(getViewTag(), getEventName(), Arguments.createMap());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected WritableMap getEventData() {
        WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
        event.putString("message", "MyMessage");
        return event;
    }
}
```

What is the alternative to `dispatch` and `RCTEventEmitter` as both are deprecated? I was looking into `RCTModernEventEmitter` and it also extends the deprecated `RCTEventEmitter`

Also i have to change the event name from `OnClickHandler` to `topOnClickHandler` in `Native Android` side. It was throwing `hermes` error. Not sure why there should be `top` prefix, why can't it just be `OnClickHandler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the react-native [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/events/RCTModernEventEmitter.java):

> This [RCTModernEventEmitter] is a transitional replacement for RCTEventEmitter that works with Fabric and non-Fabric renderers. RCTEventEmitter works with Fabric as well, but there are negative perf implications and it should be avoided.

You can use this for now as a replacement that works with Fabric.

> This [RCTModernEventEmitter] interface will *also* be deleted in the distant future and be replaced with a new interface that doesn't need the old `receiveEvent` method at all. But for the foreseeable future, this is the recommended interface to use for EventEmitters.

However, in the long run this will be removed.

There's [ReactEventEmitter](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/events/ReactEventEmitter.java) that might help based on your use-case.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a sample on how to use ReactEventEmitter. I was trying to use RCTModernEventEmitter but am stuck on what to pass surfaceId, canCoalesceEvent, customCoalesceKey and category in receiveEvent function.