# Geting ReactEventEmitter is unsupported

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I am trying to use ReactEventEmitter since RCTEventEmitter is deprecated, which is supposed to be the replacement for RCTEventEmitter but I am getting in the Logcat :
java.lang.AssertionError: Method overloading is unsupported: com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.ReactEventEmitter#receiveEvent

This is my code:

`eventEmitter = reactContext.getJSModule(ReactEventEmitter.class);`

There is not any documentation I have found only

[What are the alternatives to RCTEventEmitter and RCTModernEventEmitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73033869/what-are-the-alternatives-to-rcteventemitter-and-rctmoderneventemitter)

Is anybody face this issue?